# My APK requires Internet permission, but I didn't request it in the manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I just released an app on Google Play, and when I go there it says the following permissions are required by the app:

> **This app has access to:**
>
> - Location
>
>   - approximate location (network-based)
>   - precise location (GPS and network-based)
> - SMS
>
>   - read your text messages (SMS or MMS)
>   - receive text messages (SMS)
>   - send SMS messages
>   - edit your text messages (SMS or MMS)
> - Other
>
>   - receive data from Internet
>   - view network connections
>   - full network access
>   - run at startup
>   - prevent device from sleeping
>   - full network access
>   - run at startup

In my main Manifest, I only require the LOCATION and SMS permissions. However, I do have a manifest in the `src/beta` folder and one in `src/debug` folder which require INTERNET permissions. The APK on Google play is using the build type `release` and flavor `prod` though, so those manifests shouldn't be included in the final APK, right?

Could it be because I have code that uses `Volley` in my app, that the INTERNET permission automatically gets added? Or because I'm using Firebase?

Comment: Yup. This is it.

Comment: I think it's because of Firebase because firebase needed internet for analytics and other such things.

Comment: Try looking at your merged Manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open App AndroidManifest .
Tap on **MergedManifest** on the bottom panel of file.

All the permissions will be colored and you can check **Manifest Sources** on the right side the library which color corresponds to . Please refer below image .

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now that it's Firebase requesting the permission.